# How to interpret ternary relationship?

Tags: database-design, erd, database-diagrams

I have tried to search online on how to interpret these ternary relationships but haven't found any clear answer. Since I don't understand how to interpret it I am having trouble changing it into relations as well. In an example like this:

[image]

How exactly would I interpret this? For instance:

The line with an arrow going into `Works_in3` from the `Employee` entity, is that pointing to the `Departments` entity or the `Locations` entity? So is it implying that an Employee can only work in one department or is it implying that an employee can only work in one location or does it imply both?

Comment: In many arrow notations for relational diagrams, an arrow at one end is like a crow's foot at the other end.  So the line between Employees and Works_in might indicate many to one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of graphical representation is not one I use, so I may have to guess a bit, specially for the small arrow you can see between `employees` and `works_in`. I think you can read it as a `0,1` relation.

You can implement this model over 4 tables, like this : (`#PK` / `~FK`)

```
employees(#ssn, name, lot)
departments(#did, dname, dudget)
locations(#address, capacity)
works_in(#ssn, ~did, ~address, since)
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks to me that an employee works in at department at a location since a point in time.  I don’t recognise the diagram type as an ERD so I can’t tell what type of relationships they are but I expect that they are one to many. i.e. the works_in3 table is a link table to facilitate a many to many relationship of employee and department. As for location I expect this is where the employee worked in this department, again representing a many to many relationships, as one location could house many employees performing many roles for departments. But that’s just my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

From looking at your image, I would interpret the following:

First, to answer your question, the arrow should only be pointing to the works_in3 table.  If it was pointing to the department table it should go around works.

Table-field relationships:

Employee table: one to one relationship between ssn - name - lot (not    sure what this field really is.) Key field seems to be ssn.

Works-in3 - one to many relationship between employee identifier    (likely ssn) and since (guessing there is a department name or number in there somewhere.)

Locations: one to many relationship between    works-in3 (many locations) and location table (one address, one    capacity on each location.) Address is key field(?) - I question that    because address isn't a good key, I'm guessing there is some sort of    location identifier.

Department: one to many relationship between    department (did seems to be key field) and works-in3.

Table-table relationships:
Since only Employees -> works_in3 has an arrow, then I believe that there is a one to many relationship between employee (1 employee) and works_in3 (many potential entries possible for each employee depending on job(s) held.)

So, for each employee (always only 1 employee record) there is a current works_in3 record with since as the identifier. The other data in the record is from department (details) and location (details.)  Each employee can have many works_in3 records showing work history.